# Finding the basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image: The Problem]

I understand that the basis of a subspace defined by this equation requires you to find a combination of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ that satisfy this equation [so $(-1,0,2)$ for example]. But how do you know how many vectors are in the basis of this subspace? Couldn't a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^3$ be a line or a plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$?

Comment: It's the nullspace of a linear transformation.

Comment: Right, a basis for the kernel, right? By why does the basis of this kernel require 2 vectors? @Prospect

Comment: Because it is a plane. A plane can be determined by two vectors. One vector only defines a line.

Comment: It's a linear transformation from $\mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}$. Since it's nonzero, it will be surjective. Then the rank is 1 so the nullity is 2.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thank you @Prospect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there is a *nonzero* linear transformation $T : \mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}$ defined by $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto 2x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3$. Then the subspace in question is the nullspace of this transformation.

To compute its dimension, we can now appeal to the Dimension Theorem which states that

> For a linear transformation $T: V \to W$, $$\text{rank} (T) + \text{nullity} (T) = \dim V$$

We see that $\mathbf{R}^3$ has dimension 3 and since $T$ is nonzero, it must be surjective. Therefore, the rank is $1$ and so the nullity is seen to be $2$.

This matches up with general intuition. A plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$ has dimension two. For example, the $xy$-plane is generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any linear map  $u\colon K^n$ to $K^m$, represented by an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with coefficients in $K$, the *rank* of $u$, i.e. the rank of the matrix $A$, is equal to the *codimension* of its kernel, i.e.
$$\operatorname{rank}A=n-\dim \ker u. $$